# Custom cache reset routine for PWA

Tags: javascript, local-storage, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

We're in the early dev stage of our PWA (using workbox), probably making a few novice errors. We are constantly testing different configurations in our service worker resulting in headaches on mobile devices due to untidy cache management and clean up routines.

We've tried developing a java script routine to *remove* all (unplanned) cache files and objects (replicating a customized version of the **Clear site data** routine under Chrome desktop). We want to present Android users with a safe 'reset' routine to avoid a forced+manual clearing of site data.

[image]

We've tried iterating through localStorage, sessionStorage, caches.keys() collections (deleting all unexpected objects), followed by a registration object unregister() call, followed up with a location.reload(). But headaches persist: e.g. after a serviceWorker update > new files + logic will be present until the next page refresh thereby reverting our app back to its previous state (some cached files + containers are not deleted).

Has anyone been successful in developing a 'reset' routine for their PWA?

Comment: Note: we've realized an earlier version of service worker created a routing strategy that is no longer required under the current version of service worker; this 'old' cache object is intercepting requests for new files and returning old outdated files to browser; it's likely our delete method for clearing cache.keys() contained a bug - we're working on a better cleanup routine